# How to check if BigDecimal variable == 0 in java?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have the following code in Java;

```
BigDecimal price; // assigned elsewhere

if (price.compareTo(new BigDecimal("0.00")) == 0) {
    return true;
}
```

What is the best way to write the if condition?

Comment: Many answers are suggesting using BigDecimal's .equals() method. But that method takes scale into consideration, so is not equivalent to using compareTo().

Answer (score 657, accepted):

Use [`compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-) instead of [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

```
if (price.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) // see below
```

Comparing with the [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) constant [`BigDecimal.ZERO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ZERO) avoids having to construct a `new BigDecimal(0)` every execution.

FYI, `BigDecimal` also has constants [`BigDecimal.ONE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ONE) and [`BigDecimal.TEN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#TEN) for your convenience.

---

### Note!

The reason you can't use [`BigDecimal#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) is that it takes *scale* into consideration:

```
new BigDecimal("0").equals(BigDecimal.ZERO) // true
new BigDecimal("0.00").equals(BigDecimal.ZERO) // false!
```

so it's unsuitable for a purely numeric comparison. However, [`BigDecimal.compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) doesn't consider scale when comparing:

```
new BigDecimal("0").compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 // true
new BigDecimal("0.00").compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 // true
```

Comment: BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(price) == 0

Comment: Is there any particular reason for this implementation of BigDecimal - "new BigDecimal("0.00").equals(BigDecimal.ZERO) // false!"? Why 0.00 is not scaled down to 0 with 0 scale?

Comment: @Pavel it’s all in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: weird! price == BigDecimal.valueOf(0.00d) is not true when the price is zero!

Comment: @Mehrnoosh it never will be because in Java `==` compares object identity - ie if it’s the same object, not if the two sides have equal value. In Java, always use `.equals()` to compare things.

Comment: `The reason you can't use BigDecimal#equals() is that it takes scale into consideration`

wouldn't that be precision rather than scale?

Comment: @MarkW no, it's [scale](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scale())

Answer (score 119):

Alternatively, [signum()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#signum%28%29) can be used:

```
if (price.signum() == 0) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is faster, but compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) is more readable.

Comment: @ElYeante, you can always wrap this with method, that has more readable name, or even describes part of your business-logic, connectaed with such comparison

Comment: Unfortuntely signum() is not null-safe, whereas compareTo is, when comparing like BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(), so pay attention to that

Comment: @WeGa That's not true: `BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(null)` will throw NPE

Comment: @ACV, thanks for your vigilance. Looked at source code, compareTo() only expects non-null argument indeed.

Answer (score 29):

There is a constant that you can check against:

```
someBigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0
```

Comment: Permission to steal your terminology of a "Yoda condition" requested.

Comment: [This is fantastic](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html).

Comment: Java BigDecimal's behaviour of `equals` and `compareTo` is not as you think. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)

Comment: BigDecimal's compareTo will still throw an exception if you pass in a null.

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, I think it is worth mentioning that the behavior of equals and compareTo methods in the class BigDecimal [are not consistent with each other](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29).

This basically means that:

```
BigDecimal someValue = new BigDecimal("0.00");
System.out.println(someValue.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0); // true
System.out.println(someValue.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)); // false
```

Therefore, you have to be very careful with the scale in your `someValue` variable, otherwise you would get unexpected results.

Answer (score 6):

A simple and better way for your exemple is:

```
BigDecimal price;

if(BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(price) == 0){
    
   //Returns TRUE

}
```

Comment: Thumps up for the only null-safe solution.

Answer (score 5):

I usually use the following:

```
if (selectPrice.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 5):

You would want to use `equals()` since they are objects, and utilize the built in `ZERO` instance:

```
if (selectPrice.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO))
```

Note that `.equals()` takes scale into account, so unless selectPrice is the same scale (0) as `.ZERO` then this will return false.

To take scale out of the equation as it were:

```
if (selectPrice.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0)
```

I should note that for certain mathematical situations, `0.00 != 0`, which is why I imagine `.equals()` takes the scale into account. `0.00` gives precision to the hundredths place, whereas `0` is not that precise. Depending on the situation you may want to stick with `.equals()`.

Comment: Java BigDecimal's behaviour of `equals` and `compareTo` is not as you think. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)

Comment: Care to explain what you mean instead of linking to the docs? What I suggested should work for the OP.

Comment: Edwin Dalorzo's answer explains it quite well, actually. `equals` takes scale into account, which is not what we want here.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks for the information, in fact though there are situations where `equals` *should* be used instead of `compareTo()`. The OP doesn't specify what type of mathematics he is using, so you're right it is better to give him both option.

Answer (score 4):

GriffeyDog is definitely correct:

Code:

```
BigDecimal myBigDecimal = new BigDecimal("00000000.000000");
System.out.println("bestPriceBigDecimal=" + myBigDecimal);
System.out.println("BigDecimal.valueOf(0.000000)=" + BigDecimal.valueOf(0.000000));
System.out.println(" equals=" + myBigDecimal.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO));
System.out.println("compare=" + (0 == myBigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)));
```

Results:

```
myBigDecimal=0.000000
BigDecimal.valueOf(0.000000)=0.0
 equals=false
compare=true
```

While I understand the advantages of the BigDecimal compare, I would not consider it an intuitive construct (like the ==, <, >, <=, >= operators are).
When you are holding a million things (ok, seven things) in your head, then anything  you can reduce your cognitive load is a good thing. So I built some useful convenience functions:

```
public static boolean equalsZero(BigDecimal x) {
    return (0 == x.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO));
}
public static boolean equals(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y) {
    return (0 == x.compareTo(y));
}
public static boolean lessThan(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y) {
    return (-1 == x.compareTo(y));
}
public static boolean lessThanOrEquals(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y) {
    return (x.compareTo(y) <= 0);
}
public static boolean greaterThan(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y) {
    return (1 == x.compareTo(y));
}
public static boolean greaterThanOrEquals(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y) {
    return (x.compareTo(y) >= 0);
}
```

Here is how to use them:

```
    System.out.println("Starting main Utils");
    BigDecimal bigDecimal0 = new BigDecimal(00000.00);
    BigDecimal bigDecimal2 = new BigDecimal(2);
    BigDecimal bigDecimal4 = new BigDecimal(4);  
    BigDecimal bigDecimal20 = new BigDecimal(2.000);
    System.out.println("Positive cases:");
    System.out.println("bigDecimal0=" + bigDecimal0 + " == zero is " + Utils.equalsZero(bigDecimal0));
    System.out.println("bigDecimal2=" + bigDecimal2 + " <  bigDecimal4=" + bigDecimal4 + " is " + Utils.lessThan(bigDecimal2, bigDecimal4));
    System.out.println("bigDecimal2=" + bigDecimal2 + " == bigDecimal20=" + bigDecimal20 + " is " + Utils.equals(bigDecimal2, bigDecimal20));
    System.out.println("bigDecimal2=" + bigDecimal2 + " <= bigDecimal20=" + bigDecimal20 + " is " + Utils.equals(bigDecimal2, bigDecimal20));
    System.out.println("bigDecimal2=" + bigDecimal2 + " <= bigDecimal4=" + bigDecimal4 + " is " + Utils.lessThanOrEquals(bigDecimal2, bigDecimal4));
    System.out.println("bigDecimal4=" + bigDecimal4 + " >  bigDecimal2=" + bigDecimal2 + " is " + Utils.greaterThan(bigDecimal4, bigDecimal2));
    System.out.println("bigDecimal4=" + bigDecimal4 + " >= bigDecimal2=" + bigDecimal2 + " is " + Utils.greaterThanOrEquals(bigDecimal4, bigDecimal2));
    System.out.println("bigDecimal2=" + bigDecimal2 + " >= bigDecimal20=" + bigDecimal20 + " is " + Utils.greaterThanOrEquals(bigDecimal2, bigDecimal20));
    System.out.println("Negative cases:");
    System.out.println("bigDecimal2=" + bigDecimal2 + " == zero is " + Utils.equalsZero(bigDecimal2));
    System.out.println("bigDecimal2=" + bigDecimal2 + " == bigDecimal4=" + bigDecimal4 + " is " + Utils.equals(bigDecimal2, bigDecimal4));
    System.out.println("bigDecimal4=" + bigDecimal4 + " <  bigDecimal2=" + bigDecimal2 + " is " + Utils.lessThan(bigDecimal4, bigDecimal2));
    System.out.println("bigDecimal4=" + bigDecimal4 + " <= bigDecimal2=" + bigDecimal2 + " is " + Utils.lessThanOrEquals(bigDecimal4, bigDecimal2));
    System.out.println("bigDecimal2=" + bigDecimal2 + " >  bigDecimal4=" + bigDecimal4 + " is " + Utils.greaterThan(bigDecimal2, bigDecimal4));
    System.out.println("bigDecimal2=" + bigDecimal2 + " >= bigDecimal4=" + bigDecimal4 + " is " + Utils.greaterThanOrEquals(bigDecimal2, bigDecimal4));
```

The results look like this:

```
Positive cases:
bigDecimal0=0 == zero is true
bigDecimal2=2 <  bigDecimal4=4 is true
bigDecimal2=2 == bigDecimal20=2 is true
bigDecimal2=2 <= bigDecimal20=2 is true
bigDecimal2=2 <= bigDecimal4=4 is true
bigDecimal4=4 >  bigDecimal2=2 is true
bigDecimal4=4 >= bigDecimal2=2 is true
bigDecimal2=2 >= bigDecimal20=2 is true
Negative cases:
bigDecimal2=2 == zero is false
bigDecimal2=2 == bigDecimal4=4 is false
bigDecimal4=4 <  bigDecimal2=2 is false
bigDecimal4=4 <= bigDecimal2=2 is false
bigDecimal2=2 >  bigDecimal4=4 is false
bigDecimal2=2 >= bigDecimal4=4 is false
```

Comment: There are multiple answers explaining exactly that. What is the point of adding another answer? If you have additional information, then it is a good idea to add new answer, but this isn't the case in this post.

Comment: Point taken.  However, when I'm learning something, I like to see as many examples as possible, even if they are similar.

For you, Tom, I added my library that I found useful. Your milage may vary. :-)

Answer (score 1):

We can use  java.math.BigDecimal.signum()

Returns the signum function of this BigDecimal.

Returns:-1, 0, or 1 as the value of this BigDecimalis negative, zero, or positive.

```
     BigDecimal price; // assigned elsewhere
    
     if (price.signum() == 0) {
         return true;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share here some helpful extensions for kotlin

```
fun BigDecimal.isZero() = compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0
fun BigDecimal.isOne() = compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 0
fun BigDecimal.isTen() = compareTo(BigDecimal.TEN) == 0
```

Comment: Anyone know why Java's BigDecimal doesn't contain an "isZero" method?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(price.floatValue() == 0){
   return true; //works for 0\0.0
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(2).equals(new BigDecimal("0.00"));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43273320/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score -2):

I just wanna share helpful things. I hope that it can help you.

in Case:one = 0.0, two = 0.0;
==> BigDecimal.valueOf(one).compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(two)) == 0 // one is equal two (true)

in Case: one = 1.5, two = 1.0;
==> BigDecimal.valueOf(one).compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(two)) > 0 // one is bigger than two (true)

in Case: one = 1.5, two = 1.9;
==> BigDecimal.valueOf(one).compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(two)) < 0 // one is smaller than (true)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -10):

There is a static constant that [represents 0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ZERO):

```
BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(selectPrice)
```

You should do this instead of:

```
selectPrice.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)
```

in order to avoid the case where `selectPrice` is `null`.

Comment: Java BigDecimal's behaviour of `equals` and `compareTo` is not as you think. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)

Comment: so for second line...if selectedPrice is null then it will just throw NullPointerException.