# Null Safe Compare two bigdecimal objects having 0.0 and 0

Tags: java, java-8, bigdecimal

Initially code was :

```
            if(!Objects.equals(src.getApplicationItemCost(), dest.getApplicationItemCost())){
               log.info("Difference")
            }
```

Output:

```
      getApplicationItemCost: src:0.0| dest:0
      Difference
```

ApplicationItemCost is of type BigDecimal.

If I use `compareTo` then I have to explicitly check nulls like :

```
LOG.info("getApplicationItemCost: src:" + src.getApplicationItemCost() + "| dest:" + dest.getApplicationItemCost());
        if((src.getApplicationItemCost()==null && dest.getApplicationItemCost()!=null)
                || (src.getApplicationItemCost()!=null && dest.getApplicationItemCost()==null)
                || !Objects.equals(src.getApplicationItemCost(), dest.getApplicationItemCost())
                || src.getApplicationItemCost().compareTo(dest.getApplicationItemCost())!=0 )
```

Any suggestion to compare 0.0 and 0. Why is this difference? (May be database has Number field and when converted to big decimal it does not show 0.0?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if BigDecimal variable == 0 in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950914/how-to-check-if-bigdecimal-variable-0-in-java)

Comment: what's the return types of getApplicationItemCost() method?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher: Yes but for compareTo i need to have null checks explicitly. I am trying to avoid that. So any method or any utility.

Comment: @fatherazrael you're trying to avoid null checks? But you *need* null checks, if they might be null.

Comment: Why are 0.0 and 0 different? Look at the source and you'll see what's compared are `intVal` and `scale`. Both have the same `intVal` but a different `scale`, hence the difference in output (with and without a decimal point).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Build a comparator:

```
Comparator<BigDecimal> c = Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

(Or `nullsLast`, it doesn't matter if you're only ever comparing to zero).

Then:

```
if (c.compare(first, second) != 0) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That answers the question literally, but it’s worth noting that the prerequisites are flawed. Since the example hints that the values originate from a method like `getApplicationItemCost()`, in other words, represent monetary values, they should have the same scale in the first place or just be `BigInteger` instead of `BigDecimial` and have the scale implied. And they should never be `null` (are `null` costs different to zero costs?)…

Comment: Yes. The values contains 20.0 , 800.0 and should not be null functionally. But in first data load somehow null values got into the fields. It should be handled in Database but as of now no control of production servers. Just in test. In my changes i even included new BigDecimal(0.0) in Entity.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

> CompareToBuilder

class provided by

> org.apache.commons.lang3

as it make null safe comparison. Sample code is:

```
public static <T, U> int nullSafeComparison(T t, U u) {
        return new CompareToBuilder().append(t, u).toComparison();
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal zero = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        BigDecimal zeroPzero = new BigDecimal("0.0");

        System.out.println( zero + " " + zeroPzero);

        System.out.println(nullSafeComparison(zero, zeroPzero));
    }
```

If both numbers are same it will return 0, if 1st is greater than 2nd the result will be 1 and -1 if 1st number is less than 2nd.

Comment: @oOXAm: So if any of them are null then it will not throw any exception. Cool. Thanks. let me try

Comment: yeah, no exception. It will return 0 if both are null.

Comment: That looks like magic that is prone to fail at runtime. You declare two different type variables, `T` and `U` which do not extend `Comparable` and have no relationship at all. In other words, these type variables do not add anything to the code, it’s just like both parameters were declared as `Object`. E.g. `nullSafeComparison(new Button(), new Thread())` passes without any compiler errors.

Comment: You're right, but the whole point of the introduction of Generic is if you want to compare Integer, Long Bigdecimal, etc, you won't have to make separate methods for each. So by doing this you can use it for multiple data types.

Comment: Seems you don’t understand how to use Generics correctly. As said, the way you’ve declared the method, it’s not different to `nullSafeComparison(Object t, Object u)`, you can just pass in everything. To ensure that the arguments are compatible, there should be *one* type variable, to be used for both parameters, and it should have an appropriate bound. See [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) for an example of how to declare that the type argument must have a natural order.

Answer (score 1):

> Custom BigDecimal null safe Comparison (without any exteranal library):

```
{
    BigDecimal big1, big2; 

    big1 = new BigDecimal(0); 
    big2 = new BigDecimal(0.0); 

    int compareResult1 = compareTo(b1,null);
    int compareResult2 = compareTo(null,b2);
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int compareTo(final T c1, final T c2) {
    final boolean f1, f2;
    return (f1 = c1 == null) ^ (f2 = c2 == null) ? f1 ? -1 : 1 : f1 && f2 ? 0 : c1.compareTo(c2);
}
```

Comment: this is not null safe

Comment: This is quite complex code for a simple comparison that can be made easier and without using any external library (see Andy's answer for one such example).

Comment: I removed the type parameter from your `bigDecimalCompareTo` method; but what's the point in `bigDecimalCompareTo`, when you can just invoke `compareTo`?

Comment: Quiet complicated with assignments within comparison expressions and using the `^`  operator (which is not different to `!=` for `boolean` values). You can use a simple, straight-forward statement without additional variables like `return c1 == c2? 0: c1 == null? -1: c2 == null? 1: c1.compareTo(c2);`